# iphone EXC_BAD_ACCESS using my own class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, instance, exc-bad-access

I made my own class derived by NSObject, and here is my code:

```
-(void) parseRow:(NSDictionary*) dictionary {
    NSArray* arName = [[dictionary valueForKey:displayname] componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
    [self setDriverName:[arName objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self setDriverSurname:[arName objectAtIndex:1]];
    [arName release]; // this give problem!
}
```

and in my view:

```
driverStats = [[DriverStats alloc] init];

// driverStats is declared in the header:
DriverStats* driverStats;
@property (nonatomic,retain) DriverStats* driverStats;

[driverStats parseRow:dictionary];
```

If I add [arName release] in my class, when I exit from parseRow method, I have the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.... but it's wrong?? I used array and after I released... I think that the error will be if I didn't release the pointer.. or not???
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is easy to solve. Your NSArray *array only have 0 retainCount. Because you use a factory method componentsSeparatedByString:, it returns you an autoreleased array already. So, you don't need to release your array anymore.

Another thing you need to care about is the setDriverName: and setDriverSurname:, make sure you retain/copy the object there otherwise, when the array is released, those objects are also released and EXEC_BAD_ACCESS again

Comment: that should be correct. So, you don't need to worry about the setter any more:)